# Contextually list pages with same taxonomy term but in different vocabulary

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have two vocabularies **Course** and **Tag** like below,

```
1.) Course:

      Engineering

      Medicine

2.) Tag:

      Engineering

      Management

      Medicine
```

and I have content type named **school pages** with taxonomy term field for course, so as to select any of the course and attach each page created using this content type to any of the term in **Course** vocabulary.

What I am really looking for is, my site contains so many blog entries tagged to the terms in **Tag** vocabulary. I want to show a list of blogs tagged to the same term(but in Tags vocabulary) in pages created using **school pages** content type and tagged with same term(but in Course vocabulary).

For eg: if a school page is created with course term **medicine**, there will be a widget in the same page which will list some blogs tagged to **medicine**,  and this should be done using a single view which will dynamically **relate common terms in tag and course vocabularies**.

**My work around:**

Installed module [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference),

Applied following config:

**FILTER CRITERIA**

Content: Published (Yes)

Content: Type (= Blog entry)

**RELATIONSHIPS:**

Entity Reference: course_name

**CONTEXTUAL FILTERS**

(Taxonomy term entity referenced from field_course_name) Taxonomy term: Name

Comment: It seems like your workaround should work. Or doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the [equi_join](https://drupal.org/project/equi_join) module. It would allow you to join one vocab to another based on just the term name so you wouldn't need the entity reference.

There is only a dev release available however I've had some success with it as it is...